# How to change default constructor?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, servicestack

ServiceStack generates typescript code based on my backend api classes. 
Those typescript classes have default constructors, which looks like this.

```
export class ExamleClass
{
public constructor(init?:Partial<ExamleClass>) { (<any>Object).assign(this, init); }
}
```

Because of `<any>Object` there are a lot of warnings with message "Prefer 'as any' instead of '' when doing type assertions". How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<type>` is valid TypeScript syntax for casting an object, which is needed in TypeScript projects by default without any library references as `Object.assign` isn't available.

If you upgrade to the latest version of ServiceStack it now uses `as any` syntax for casting in its [TypeScript Add Reference](https://docs.servicestack.net/typescript-add-servicestack-reference) feature:

```
public constructor(init?:Partial<ExamleClass>) { (Object as any).assign(this, init); }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code you don't have to do any cast, `Object` is only a class, the function you're calling is static.

But if you really want to do the cast use `(Object as any)` instead, beause the use of `<>` may cause conflicts in JSX files (React files).